# compression happened before __WB_MANIFEST injection

Tags: webpack, compression, service-worker, workbox-webpack-plugin, webpack-5

I put a console.log for filename in `compression-webpack-plugin` and
at the very beginning of the build process, a log will be printed, actually, after the contents of `sw.js` file copied to a newly created file called `service-worker.js`, but at this moment there is no information about `self.__WB_MANIFEST` which must be preached by workbox `precacheAndRoute`. At the end of the build process, when information arrived, an array ( preached times with their revision) will be replaced with `self.__WB_MANIFEST` and got injected into `service-worker.js`, but no compression log will happen.
hence there will be an incompatibility with a compressed and original file for `service-wroker.js`.

**webpack plugins**

```js
{
  plugins: [
    // ...
    new WorkboxPlugin.InjectManifest({
      swSrc: './src/setup/sw.js',
      swDest: 'service-worker.js',
      exclude: [/\.(gz|br)$/],
      maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 10 * 1024 * 1024,
    }),
    // ...
    new CompressionPlugin({
      filename(pathData) {
        console.log(pathData)
        return '[path][base].gz'
      },
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      minRatio: 0.8,
      test: /\.(js|css|html|svg|wasm)$/,
   })
  ]
}
```

**packges.json**

```json
{
  "webpack": "^5.4.0",
  "compression-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.5",
  "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.0-alpha.3",
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/2667#issuecomment-726173739), this issue is fixed and you should upgrade `compression-webpack-plugin` to v6.1.1.